# Submenu with fixed size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu and sub menu, I want to make the submenu that appears for all the elements with fixed size. Something like that menu of this site: http://designscrazed.org/

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li class="current-menu-item"> element 1
<ul>
<li> <a href="#">sub element 1.2</a></li>
<li> sub element 2.2</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> element 2
<ul>
<li> sub element 1.2</li>
<li> sub element 2.2</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> element 3
<ul>
<li> sub element 1.3</li>
<li> sub element 2.3</li>
</ul>
</li>
 <li> element 4
 <ul>
 <li> sub element 1.4</li>
 <li> sub element 2.4</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li> element 5
 <ul>
 <li> sub element 1.5</li>
 <li> sub element 2.5</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li> element 6
<ul>
<li> sub element 1.6</li>
 <li> sub element 2.6</li>
</ul>
</li>
 <li> element 7
 <ul>
<li> sub element 1.7</li>
<li> sub element 2.7</li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul>






</div>
```

and this is my CSS :

```
    #menu{
    background-color:magenta;
    float:right;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    margin:10px 90px;
    padding: 0 0px;
    text-align:center;

    }

    #menu ul li{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    top:0px; 
    float:left;
    margin:0 5px;
    padding:8px 0;
    cursor:pointer;




    }
#menu ul  li.current-menu-item
{

background:#ddd
} 

#menu ul li:hover{

background-color:#7F7F7F;

}

#menu ul ul{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;
background:#fff;
padding:0;
right: 50%;
margin-right: -85px;



}


#menu ul ul li{
float:none;
width:20em;
background-color:cyan;
margin:0px 0;


    }

#menu ul li:hover > ul{

display:block;  
left:auto;
right:0;
margin-right:-10px;

         }
```

Comment: Just a note: using a fixed size is going to be a messy job when you are trying to make your website responsive. How about using `%` or `em`

Comment: @kode.Error404 I want to have the submenu for all the parent element having the same width and height, and only change the contents inside each sub menu however I want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

What I did was changed the target for the `position: absolute` elements to `#menu` by set it to `position: relative` instead of the `li`'s

By doing so, the left/top/right values computes against the `#menu` hence position the `submenu`'s at its left/bottom position.

```css
#menu{
  background-color:magenta;
  float:right;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  /*display:inline-block;*/
  margin:10px 90px;
  padding: 0 0px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;  
}

#menu ul li { 
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  list-style:none;
  top:0px; 
  float:left;
  margin:0 5px;
  padding:8px 0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#menu ul  li.current-menu-item {
  background:#ddd
} 

#menu ul li:hover{
  background-color:#7F7F7F;
}
#menu ul ul {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0;
  right: 0;
}
#menu ul ul li{
  float:none;
  width:20em;
  background-color:cyan;
  margin:0px 0;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul{
  display:block;  
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="current-menu-item"> element 1
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">sub element 1.2</a></li>
        <li> sub element 2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> element 2
      <ul>
        <li> sub element 1.2</li>
        <li> sub element 2.2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> element 3
      <ul>
        <li> sub element 1.3</li>
        <li> sub element 2.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> element 4
      <ul>
        <li> sub element 1.4</li>
        <li> sub element 2.4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> element 5
      <ul>
        <li> sub element 1.5</li>
        <li> sub element 2.5</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> element 6
      <ul>
        <li> sub element 1.6</li>
        <li> sub element 2.6</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> element 7
      <ul>
        <li> sub element 1.7</li>
        <li> sub element 2.7</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, would you elaborate some more

Comment: @DavidPowell Added an explanation ... was I clear enough?